# How to get Id as per the max date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table (with sample data shown)

```
    Id  WayBillNo       Date                       Status
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   501263027308    2023-03-10 23:59:59.000    DELIVERED
    2   501263027308    2023-03-10 09:01:12.000    OUT FOR DELIVERY
    3   501263027308    2023-03-09 16:53:25.000    IN-TRANSIT
    4   501263027308    2023-03-09 03:40:37.000    IN-TRANSIT
    5   501263027308    2023-03-08 01:36:24.000    ARRIVED AT DESTINATI
    6   501263027308    2023-03-03 15:59:23.000    IN-TRANSIT
    7   501263027308    2023-03-01 20:50:38.000    IN-TRANSIT
    8   501263027312    2023-03-05 12:11:29.000    ARRIVED AT DESTINATI
    9   501263027312    2023-03-04 23:27:27.000    IN-TRANSIT
    10  501263027312    2023-03-03 19:11:06.000    IN-TRANSIT
    11  501263027312    2023-03-02 14:26:06.000    IN-TRANSIT
    12  501263027312    2023-03-01 20:50:38.000    IN-TRANSIT
```

I want the output as below (i.e., the Ids based on the max date for individual way bill no):

```
Id
---
1   
8
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: @DaleK.. I  was able to get the waybill numbers as per the max dates but not by Ids.. 

select WayBillNo, max([date]) from tbl group by WayBillNo

Comment: Add your attempt to your question

Comment: You can use the following trick to get the maxest rows: select top 1 with ties * from yourtable order by row_number() over(partition by WayBillNo order by Date DESC);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved it:

```
select *
from tbl S
inner join (
    select WayBillNo,
        MaxDate=max([date])
    from tbl
    group by WayBillN
) T on T.WayBillNo=S.WayBillNo and T.MaxDate=S.Date
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id
from table_name1 
where case when date in (
    select max_date as date
    from (
        select max(date) as max_date
        from table_name1
        group by waybillno
    ) t1
) then 1 else 0 end
```

We can use `group by`

Answer (score -1):

The below query should fetch you the desired result,

SELECT
Id
FROM
TestTable
WHERE DateCol
IN
(
SELECT MAX(DateCol) FROM TestTable
GROUP BY WayBillNo
)

Answer (score -1):

```
select Id
from table one
inner join (
select WayBillNo, max(Date) as MaxDate from table group by WayBillNo)
two on one.WayBillNo=two.WayBillNo and one.Date=two.MaxDate
```